# How should I route search modes? Different resources? One resource? Multiple actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, resources, routes

I have a resource named Cimgs
You can see them in the #index
Them can be searched by content, via Sphinx
Also can be searched by tags
And can be searched by another related Cimg, checking for tags collisions

And here is my question: which is the better way to route this?
Should I pass an extra parameter to the #index and search accordingly to the parameter? After all they all use the same view.
Or should I create an action for each search method?
Or maybe a whole resource?

I'm currently doing the following:

```
  resources :cimgs, path: 'pics' do
    collection do
      get 'search(/:q)', action: :index, search_by: :content, as: :search_by_content
      get 'tags/:tag',   action: :index, search_by: :tags,    as: :search_by_tag
      get 'page/:page', action: :index
    end

    member do
      get 'related', action: :index, search_by: :related, as: :search_by_related
    end
  end

  root :to => 'cimgs#index'
```

The problem is that I'm using Kaminari for paging, and it doesn't detect the page/:page for another route than the root. (I don't actually know the mechanism that it uses to detect the page/:page)

And here is my controller action:

```
  def index
    @cimgs = case params[:search_by]
      when :content; Cimg.content_search     params[:q],   params[:page], request.remote_ip
        return redirect_to @cimgs[0] if @cimgs.length == 1
      when :tag;     Cimg.search_by_tag      params[:tag], params[:page]
      when :related; Cimg.search_related_to  params[:id],  params[:page]
      else;          Cimg.get_for_front_page               params[:page]
    end

    render :index
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep them all in a single action.  My assumption is that eventually, you'll decide it's useful to combine your search methods ("I want an image that's related to this other image, but has the tag 'ketchup'.").  That'll be easy to do if you have a single action that handles all your searches already, but much more difficult - or at least involving lots of duplicate code - if you have separate actions.

I do something similar in a site I'm working on.  I take a master search hash as `params[:search]`, and then have each individual search term in that hash.  And then, since I've made a named_scope (might be a different name in Rails 3) for each search option, I can do something like:

```
scope = MyModel.scoped
params[:search].each_pair do |key, value|
    scope = scope.send(key, value)
end
@models = scope.all
```

Plus some basic error checking, but that's the idea.

Hope that helps!